# Can I use a 3-phase driver like FNB41560 on 1- and 2-phase motors too?

Tags: induction-motor, vfd, asynchronous

I want to reduce complexity on buying many different parts and design different circuits. So I'm thinking if I can buy just [FNB41560](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/FNB41560B2_D-1809510.pdf)s that are well priced and simple and are capable of driving 3-phase AC motors, but using it also to drive 1- and 2-phase AC motors.

All the motors I will use are simple AC asynchronous ones that vary velocity by frequency. It’s an "inverter"(variable frequency inverter drives - VFD) type application to vary speed.

Comment: Did you mwan dual line (L1+L2)  or quadrature when you said 2-phse?  Those are generally obsolete  with special transfos

Comment: oh, yes i mean L1+L2 no neuter . actually the 2 phases i said are monophasic too. its 220V motors being used in 127V mains(L+N) but as L+L giving the 220V

Comment: I think it's more accurate to describe it as 240V split phase 120+120

Answer (score 2):

As long as the specifications for the Intelligent Power Module (IPM) are appropriate for the voltages and currents required for the motors, I see no reason why they would not work for single phase motors (PSC types) as well as the intended three phase motors. Two phase motors are rare and would require a four element H-bridge. For the capacitor run motors, it would be best to remove the capacitor and drive that winding with the equivalent voltage and phase angle supplied by the capacitor, especially if you need to vary the speed more than 20% or so. Otherwise, the usual V/f algorithm will cause excessive current through the capacitor into the auxiliary winding at higher than base speed, and lower speeds would result in insufficient current to achieve rated torque.

Comment: Start run caps won't shift 90 deg at low V/f and you meant dual line single phase

Comment: I don't know what dual line single phase is. Two phase motors have two equal windings spaced at 90 degrees and require four power connections. https://www.tme.eu/en/news/library-articles/page/43518/three-phase-two-phase-and-single-phase-motors-how-they-are-built-what-they-are-used-for/

Comment: its only single phases and 3-ph , i will edit it . the 2-ph i said are actualy 220V monos so using in 127V L+L .

Comment: about capacitors , any motor wired with it i will remove and drive it directly. i get what you mean, sometimes people wire 3-ph motors with only 2 phases and use a "starting capacitor" for the motor to accumulate that bit of extra energy for the motor to start.